# Xcode - How to show the simulator as a real iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have this issue.

My simulator looks like this:

[image]

And i want to show it, like this:

[image]

How can i do it?...

**EDIT:** This is how it looks with scale 100%.
[image]

Comment: In your xcode menu  have window section click that select scale sub menu change your size of simulator

Comment: i given actual result on my second screen shot what i mistake why not accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot in your question shows you're using the retina display simulator.
The simulator removes the phone image if you're using a non-retina display Mac to run the simulator.

To get the effect you want you need to run the iPhone simulator as an iPhone Device.
You can switch to this mode by going to the Hardware -> Device -> iPhone option when in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

try this. it works 100%.........................................

[image]

other simulator

[image]

Comment: set your scale size as 75% or 50%